# How to use setState with fetch API on form submit in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and wanted to play around with the fetchAPI. I want to use the GoogleBooks API to display a list of books that matches a query string which the user can enter in an input field.

I've managed to make the call to the Google API and have used setState but I can't get the state to stick. If I want to render the state after fetching the data, the state appears as undefined.

I have a feeling that React renders the HTML first and then sets the state after making the API call.

I'd appreciate if you can have a look at my component.

Thank you!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Search extends Component{
 constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state = {
  books: []

}
this.books = this.state.book
this.title = ''
this.handleChange = (e) => {
  this.title = e.target.value

}
this.handleSubmit = (e) => {
  let results = '';
  e.preventDefault();
  const apiKey = 'AIzaSyBuR7JI6Quo9aOc4_ij9gEqoqHtPl-t82g'
  fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${this.title}&key=${apiKey}`)
  .then(response => response.json()).then(jsonData => {
    this.setState({
      books: jsonData
    })
    console.log(jsonData)
  })

}
}
 render(){

return(
  <div className="col-md-12">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form-group">
    <label>Enter title</label>
    <input onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" ref="title" type="text" placeholder="Enter title"></input>
    <button  type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div>
      <li>this.state.books</li>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
<li>this.state.books</li>
```

This is just rendering a string.

Instead, you can use `map` to show data from book you get from the response.

Here's a working example:

```
 <div>
   {
      this.state.books.items &&
      this.state.books.items.map(book => <li>{book.etag}</li>)
    }
 </div>
```

Comment: What an oversight on my part. Thank you Colin!